# wifi Hotspot connection trouble from iPhone

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

I find hotspot connection from iPhone takes time whereas connection from hotspot device happen easily. [image: Wifi list]

In the wifi list, MyPhone is my iPhone hotspot connection but it is not having connection. It happen many times.
Also, when I use Ethernet then Auto Ethernet does not work as Realtek ethernet was working. But there also some issue was there so I have deleted that once. Now, Auto Ethernet rarely work. How to restore RealTek ethernet.

Please help.

Also, Hotspot through Android mobile over wifi always used to work. Just iPhone hotspot over wifi does not connect easily most of the time. I need to toggle Wifi (on/off) few times then suddenly I see hotspot name appears  in Ubuntu available wifi list.

Comment: My all wifi setting has gone. I have installed wcd network manager suggestion here in another question. That was of no help to me so I uninstalled. Now, nothing is coming on Wifi list. In safe mode, internet is working. Please help to restore everything and make it working.